# how to return an array of (bigint, double precision) from a function in order to convert it to json array

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

What I need is a string/text json-compliant array of arrays like the following:

```
[
    [1421420100, 14214201003487],
    [1421420101, 14214201003487],
    [1421420109, 14214201003487]
...
]
```

in order to return it from the server to the client without any further elaboration.

I have a function that queries on a table that returns the two fields, but I would like to return an array of arrays in order to call the function and then call `array_to_json`. Then, I would like to convert it into text/string.

Is that possible? Can an array of arrays have two different types?

Comment: why dont use array of objects? [{type1,type2}]

Comment: because the expected output is what I posted, but in case is not possibile I'll do that way

Comment: Can an array of arrays have two different types?  yse, it can

Comment: can you please show me the way? I was sure that each element should have the same type. Allowed: `{{1,4}, {5,9}}`, not allowed `{{1,'4'}, {5,'9'}}`. Maybe I'm wrong? According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167828/multiple-data-types-array-in-postgresql) no

Comment: @Ali7091: A Postgres array can only include elements of the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres arrays **cannot** hold elements of different type.
But you can return an **array of composite type** `(bigint, double precision)` instead. The type needs to be registered in the database instance. Either with an explicit `CREATE TYPE` statement, or implicitly as row type of a table or view.

Example:

```
CREATE TYPE int8_float AS (b bigint, f float);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_combo_arr()
  RETURNS int8_float[] 
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
   SELECT ARRAY(SELECT (int8_col, float_col)::int8_float FROM tbl);
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_combo_arr();
```

`float` is an alias for `double precision` in Postgres.

There may be a smarter solution, like returning data type `json` or a set instead of the array.

Related:

- [Return type for function with array_agg()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228125/return-type-for-function-with-array-agg/20228715#20228715)
- [PostgreSQL - best way to return an array of key-value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129855/postgresql-best-way-to-return-an-array-of-key-value-pairs/9134316#9134316)

Comment: nice "standard" solution! What about returning a TABLE with the two columns instead? Which of the two do you think is more efficient? I was thinking about returning it and then iterate over it with a cursor

Comment: @Bertuz: I would prefer a table function with two columns. Probably more efficient for big sets.